# Unexpected blank space under FlatList on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-flatlist

[image: app screen (gap under "teste 6")]

there is a weird space between the FlatList and the navigation bar. it only occurs on iOS and works as expected on Android (no gap between them). when I put a View tag around the FlatList, it fills the gap but I can't scroll the list all the way down. the gap is about 35px tall

I've already checked and there's no margin/padding nor anything there, it's just a blank space.

[image: screen on android, working as expected]

```
<List
   theme={theme}
   data={chats
      .filter(el => el.name.search(new RegExp(search, "i")) !== -1)
      .sort(sortChats)}
   renderItem={renderItem}
   keyExtractor={item => item._id}
/>

export default List = Styled.FlatList`
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-right: ${({ theme }) => theme.screen.padding.right};
  margin-right: -${({ theme }) => theme.screen.padding.right};
`;

const ItemContainer = Styled.View`
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  opacity: ${({ offline }) => (offline ? 0.5 : 1)};
`;

const ChatInfo = Styled.View`
  flex: 1;
`;
```